# How do I call the name of an algorithm from another algorithm?

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithms

I'm writing my pseudocode wrapped inside `\begin{algorithm}[H] \begin{algorithmic} ...`, now I want to be able to cite(function call) another algorithm that I will define later in my latex code so that I won't need to update the name of the referenced algorithm when it get renamed. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Store the function name in a macro in the preamble? (`\newcommand*\algoOneName{<name>}`)